# Examples of very long proofs which were condensed to a very small size

Tags: soft-question, big-list

While reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_mathematical_proofs?wprov=sfla1) article, I learned that the original proof of the Abel Ruffini theorem was about 500 pages, which was later condensed to just 6 pages. Immediately after reading this, a question came to my mind:

> What are some examples where a very large proof was condensed to a very small size?

Comment: de Branges' proof of the Bieberbach Conjecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem I think a question very like yours might have been asked once here or maybe at MathOverflow.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you could include it as an answer.

Comment: First I'd want to be convinced the question's not a duplicate.

Comment: I found three closely related questions on MathOverflow, many of the examples cited there would make good answers here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43820/extremely-messy-proofs/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95837/examples-of-theorems-with-proofs-that-have-dramatically-improved-over-time/ and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/